# Tutorials on how to create a Framework?

Tags: frameworks

I was wondering is there any tutorial on how to create a FrameWork?, i am getting used to use some of them but i am very interested on seeing how they work, and how the desicions for one approach are related.

I have been reading  and i found the following tutorials, but is there any other you know?, other languages like python, PHP or Ruby?

http://www.admixweb.com/2009/05/20/how-to-easily-create-a-javascript-framework-part-1/
http://dailyjs.com/2010/12/02/framework-review/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it is not geared towards the languages you mention, there is this book: [http://www.amazon.com/Framework-Design-Guidelines-Conventions-Libraries/dp/0321545613](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321545613)